# How can I allow a given application to access a given folder and its content

Tags: selinux, application

I recently installed a game through Steam, but some of the assets of the game aren't loaded.

After a few investigations on the web, the Windows users who had the same problem were adviced to turn off their antivirus in the process of solving the problem.

Using Fedora, I transposed the solution and tried to turn off SELinux with `setenforce 0` before running the game. It does work! The assets were correctly loaded ingame.

As I don't really want to turn off SELinux for obvious reasons, I would like to allow that particular application (the game) to read/write that particular folder (the assets).

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Well then obviously `SELinux` is the problem here. For a starter look at the `ausearch -m avc -ts recent`  output.  You could (usually)  then use `audit2allow` to generate the policy.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try to do some basic SELinux trouble shooting, like:

1. `restorecon /path/to/your/game`

   - no particular output expected
2. `grep -i =avc /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep -i my_cool_game | audit2allow -M my_cool_game
   semodule -i my_cool_game.pp`

   - where my_cool_game is game name, more like eg. `quake2` instead of `quake2.exe` ;-)